# Reactive Kafka: No error while creating stream for a non-existent topic

Tags: apache-kafka, reactive-kafka

We recently switched to Reactive Kafka. It seems kafka does not throw any error if the topic exists while creating stream for the topic. Why is it so?

I know that existence of a topic can explicitly be checked with `AdminUtils.topicExists(zkClient, topicName)`. Is there a way to force reactive kafka to check if topic exists on its own before creating streams?

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in the Kafka Broker settings. The related config is `auto.create.topics.enable` and it's true by default. Setting it to false should cause the underlying Apache Kafka client to throw an error if a topic does not exist, instead of automatically creating a new topic.

See the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) for more info.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the broker config.